# How to animate a list when an element is added on top? (react)

Tags: reactjs, css-animations

I have a list of elements. I add elements one by one from sockets. If an element arrives, I add it first, and delete the last one.

Initial state:

- Element 1
- Element 2
- Element 3
- Element 4

State after adding a new element Element 5:

- Element 5
- Element 1
- Element 2
- Element 3

And here I want to add animation so that the new element smoothly appears on top, and all the others smoothly go down ( i.e. as if they were scrolling ), and the last one went into full transparency.

I tried 'react-transition-group' like this:

Template:

```
<TransitionGroup className="list">
                {
                    list.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <CSSTransition 
                                   key={item.id} 
                                   classNames="list-item" 
                                   timeout={500}>
                                <div key={item.id}>Элемент {item.id}</>
                            </CSSTransition>
                        );
                    })
                 }
</TransitionGroup>
```

Styles:

```
.list-item-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: opacity 500ms, transform 500ms;
}

.list-item-enter-done {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.list-item-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: opacity 500ms, transform 500ms;
}

.list-item-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

But only the first and last element of the list can be animated this way. Elements 2 and 3 are simply redrawn in new places without a smooth transition.

Is there another approach for such an animation?

Comment: Are you restricted to the use of react-transtion-group? or can you use another library if suggested?

Comment: I can use any library I want. (except jQuery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are able to use other libraries, I'd suggest using framer-motion, which, in my opinion is a little bit more "ready-to-use".

Anyways, to achieve what you described, with framer-motion you'd have to wrap your list around the `ul` tag of the library and every item with the `li` one:

```js
<motion.ul layout layoutId={"list"} className="list-container">
        <AnimatePresence>
          {list.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <motion.li
                initial={{ x: -200, opacity: 0 }}
                animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
                exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                key={item}
              >
                <div
                  key={item.id}
                >
                  Test {item.id}
                </div>
              </motion.li>
            );
          })}
        </AnimatePresence>
</motion.ul>
```

With `list-container` being a css class having the `flex-direction` property set to `column-reverse`.
Now everytime you add a list item the item will be pushed to the top and the rest will scroll 'animatedfully' down

Anyways, here is a codesanbox of the code I provided above, you can tweak the animations to your desire:

[image: Edit List Push Animation]

For further documentation you can visit: https://www.framer.com/motion/introduction/